# Keep elements in list of tuples contained in another list

Tags: python, list

so I have this list of badWords:

```
badWords = ["nu", "să", "o", "și", "de", "i", "pe", "cu", "ce", "mai", "la", "în", "un", "se", "mi", "eu", "ca",
                "că"]
```

And I have this double list in this format:

```
word_list = [(673, 'de'), (606, 'și'), (518, 'o'), (486, 'să'), (484, 'nu'), (469, 'i'), (348, 'pe'), (309, 'răzvan'), (308, 'cu'), (304, 'ce'), (302, 'mai')]
```

I have tried to do this, in order to delete an entry which match my list of bad words

```
for x in range(len(word_list)):
    for y in range(len(word_list[x])):
        for word in badWords:
            if(word_list[x][y] == word):
                word_list.remove(x)
```

But I get this:

> Error: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of multiple things.  TL/DR: A) generally using remove inside a for loop is a bad idea.  B) You probably just want to do
cleaned_word_list = [x for x in word_list if x[1] not in badWords]

Comment: `remove` takes an element of a list, not an index.`x` is an index in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off creating a new list with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and keeping only those tuples with a second item not present in `badWords`:

```
[i for i in word_list if i[1] not in badWords]
# [(309, 'răzvan')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator `in` works much faster with sets than with lists:

```
s = set(badWords)
list(filter(lambda x: x[1] not in s, word_list))
# [(309, 'răzvan')]
```